# Jquery UI Draggable: roll back all the changes on destroy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there any possible way to remove all the changes made by the draggable plugin when its instance is destroyed (or a step before that)? I tried doing something like:

```
if (target) {
      $(target).draggable("option","revert",true);
      $(target).draggable("destroy");
}
```

Doesn't work.

EDIT:

My guess is that after I change the revert option, it basically sets the starting point where the element is now, not where it was initially.

EDIT2:

More code:

```
  $(editbtn).toggle(
                function() {
                    var target;
                    $(this).attr('data', 'on');
                    //appedning editor to body
                    editor.draggable().appendTo($('body'));

                    //make hints selectable
                    $('.ui-hint').live('click.hintAdmin', function(e) {

                        //get rid of prev binds/drags if present
                        if (target) {                                    
                                $(target).draggable();
                                $(target).draggable("destroy");
                        }
                        $(save).unbind('click.hintAdmin');
                        $(del).unbind('click');
                        $('.ui-hintAdmin-edit-hl').removeClass('ui-hintAdmin-edit-hl');
                        $('.ui-hintAdmin-hider').remove();

                        target = e.target;
                        var $this = $(this);
                        //get hint instances and targets
                        var hint_t = $(this).prev();
                        var hint = $(this).prev().data('hint');

                        var offset_start, offset_stop, offset_final, axis;


                        $(target).append(del);

                        self._hintHider(hint, $this);

                        //making delete work and clean after itself
                        $(del).on('click.hintAdmin', function() {
                            $('.ui-hintAdmin-edit-hl').removeClass('ui-hintAdmin-edit-hl');
                            $(save).unbind('click.hintAdmin');
                            $(label).html('');
                            $(edit).val('');
                            $(del).unbind('click');
                            $(target).draggable("destroy");
                            hint_t.hint("destroy");
                            $('.ui-hintAdmin-hider').remove();

                        })



                        $(target).addClass('ui-hintAdmin-edit-hl');
                        $(label).html('Editing hint # ' + hint.options.id);
                        $(edit).val(hint.options.text);

                        //choosing the axis 

                        switch (hint.options.position) {
                            case 'top':
                                axis = 'x';
                                break;
                            case 'bottom':
                                axis = 'x';
                                break;
                            case 'left':
                                axis = 'y';
                                break;
                            case 'right':
                                axis = 'y';
                                break;
                        }



                        offset_start = $(target).offset();
                        $(target).draggable({
                            axis: axis,
                            grid: [5, 5],
                            stop: function(e, ui) {
                                offset_stop = ui.offset;
                                switch (hint.options.position) {
                                    case 'top':
                                        offset_final = '' + offset_stop.left - offset_start.left + '';
                                        console.log('top' + offset_final);
                                        break;
                                    case 'bottom':
                                        offset_final = '' + offset_start.left - offset_stop.left + '';
                                        console.log('bottom' + offset_final);
                                        break;
                                    case 'left':
                                        offset_final = '' + offset_stop.top - offset_start.top + '';
                                        console.log('left' + offset_final);
                                        break;
                                    case 'right':
                                        offset_final = '' + offset_stop.top - offset_start.top + '';
                                        console.log('right' + offset_final);
                                        break;
                                }
                                ;

                            }
                        });

       {rest of the code . .}
}
```

Comment: Check if this is working... $(target).draggable({ revert: true });

Comment: @Nikhil Checked, works, and object notation doesn't work either :(

Comment: I didn't get part "object notation doesn't work either" ?

Comment: @Nikhil I meant {revert: true}, because i've already initialized it earlier and according to documentation you can only change the options later using "option", "name", value.

Comment: can you post whole code related to draggable if possible ?

Comment: @Nikhil Posted more of the code.

Comment: may be this will help you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014196/jquery-draggable-revert-on-button-click